# NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange doesn't call

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I work on Core Data sync with iCloud. It works great, but Core Data updates changes only after leave app. I was learning about it and I found this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes. I've decide to use:
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(storeRemoteChange(_:)), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)` In **storeRemoteChange(_:))** I've put print command to check when Notification fire. Notification doesn't fire, sometimes after 5 minutes, but changes saved on iCloud are immediately.

My code from persistentContainer initialize contains

```
    privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    let remoteChangeKey = "NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey"
    privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber,
                               forKey: remoteChangeKey)


    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    container.viewContext.transactionAuthor = appTransactionAuthorName
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    
    do {
        try container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
    } catch {
        fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to pin viewContext to the current generation:\(error)")
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(storeRemoteChange(_:)), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you looking for:  try viewContext.save() ?

Comment: Please tell me precisely what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how the data is handled thru its lifecycle at your project I don't know, but I will try with some general input.

To find the correct way to chose what data to keep if local data and cloud data is different is not a right or wrong answer to me at least.

We ca assume cloud is always correct you can mirror

[image]

Or you can when you set a Core data Entity

```
extension myEntity: Comparable {
static func setEntity(_ id: String, info: EntityInfo, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> MyEntity {
    let request = fetchRequest(NSPredicate(format: "id_ = %@", string))
    let results = (try? context.fetch(request)) ?? []
    if let entity = results.first {
        return entity
    } else {
        let entity = Entity(context: context)
        entity.id = id
        entity.name = info.name
        try context.save()
        return airline
    }
}

static func fetchRequest(_ predicate: NSPredicate) -> NSFetchRequest<MyEtity> {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Airline>(entityName: "MyEntity")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name_", ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = predicate
    return entity
}

struct EntityInfo {
    let name: String
}
```

}

Or when a context updates, maybe you have two context, and only update the one, and need to call the other for your data to run as you want in your notification block

```
var savedOK = false
```

managedObjectContext.performAndWait() {

```
// Perform operations with the context.

do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
    savedOK = true
} catch {
    print("Error saving context: \(error)")
}
```

}

Comment: When I was testing my app I was typing changes from iCloud Console. So probably my issue doesn’t depend on saving method

Comment: Are you thinking the observer function setup is the culprit? I know core data has a set cycle for syncing data, and you wrote closing the app made it work. Guessed that triggered a correct sync.

Comment: That triggered a correct sync, because in sceneDidEnterBackground method app automatically saved context. Currently seems that issue is in observer function. Otherwise in Apple's Docs we can read, that iCloud automatically sends remote notification after save changes - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/syncing_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit - "Download CloudKit Changes into Core Data
" Headline